# Bullying littermates

Tags: cats

Littermates both fixed. One male much larger and the runt female. He is attacking her and today he hurt her. Is there anything we can do to combat this problem?

Comment: Age? A certain amount of wrestling is normal;.if they still curl up with each other later there's probably no serious argument, just a sometimes annoying sister/brother.